# How to I get diffmerge running as the merge tool for git

Tags: git, diffmerge

I'm running osx 10.9 with git and I'm trying to get diffmerge running as my merge tool. I've installed diffmerge and can launch it from my bash shell -

```
$ diffmerge
```

however when I try and set it up as my merge tool -

```
$ git config --global merge.tool diffmerge
$ git config --global mergetool.diffmerge.cmd "diffmerge --merge --result=\$MERGED \$LOCAL \$BASE \$REMOTE"
$ git config --global mergetool.diffmerge.trustExitCode true
```

And run

```
$ git mergetool
```

I get the following output -

```
git config option merge.tool set to unknown tool: diffmerge
Resetting to default...

This message is displayed because 'merge.tool' is not configured.
```

Any idea's why this is failing? (it might be worth noting that diffmerge isn't listed as a valid tool when I run `git mergetool --tool-help`)

Comment: Take a look at your ~/.gitconfig directly and verify those configs got set.

Comment: I got the same error, and got a little farther by following the instructions for setting up diffmerge with Cygwin here: http://sourcegear.com/diffmerge/webhelp/sec__git__windows__msysgit.html. But their .sh wrapper didn't work so I gave up and used meld. Life's much better now.